# How to insert image in a Rectangle using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

Here am tried to place a image on a **colored rectangle** but image didn't appear.

Please suggest any answer.

[image: PDF example.]

here is my code:-

```
pcb.RoundRectangle(iXCoordinate + 5, iYCoordinate, 500, 100, 5);
pcb.SetRGBColorFill(198, 226, 255);
pcb.Fill();
pcb.RoundRectangle(iXCoordinate + 5, iYCoordinate, 500, 100, 5); pcb.Stroke();
pcb.ResetRGBColorFill();

pcb.BeginText();
pcb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, false), 10);
pcb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, sCustomerName, iXCoordinate + 30, iYCoordinate, 0); iYCoordinate -= 12;
pcb.EndText();

iTextSharp.text.Image myImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(@"D:\Maruti\Resources\logo.jpg");
myImage.SetAbsolutePosition(iXCoordinate + 410, iYCoordinate - 40);
myImage.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(35);
myImage.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(80);
doc.Add(myImage);
```

Comment: Your code is not self-contained. Can you perhaps change your example so that it is?

Comment: set a break point after `myImage=...` and check if it loaded (not null), Also check iXCoordinate and iYCoordinate

Comment: also please share a sample result pdf for analysis.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Sir please visit the link PDF example in the post @ mkl

Comment: Your "PDF example" points to an image, not the actual PDF. Stack overflow does not allow to upload anything but images, PDFs may be transformed to an image format. For an analysis the actual PDF is needed, though. Usually one creates a public file share (e.g. a public share on google drive or dropbox; please no file sharing service that drowns the visitor in ads or even attempts to make him download adwarez or worse) and posts the URL here.

Comment: That been said, is the image probably mostly hidden by the rectangle, only a bit being visible near the bottom right corner of the rectangle? In that case your description *"image didn't appear"* would be wrong, though, as it clearly does appear.

Comment: Actually that was example to show. Here i want to place a image inside rectangle. But image was hidden by rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you combine immediate drawing of forms and text to the page content stream (using the `PdfContentByte pcb` which you most likely retrieved as `DirectContent` from your `PdfWriter`) and indirect drawing of the image through the iText layout mechanism (using the `Document doc`).

Elements added in such a mixed way do not necessarily occur in the result content in the order in which you added them in your code. In your case for example the image you add last (via `Document`) actually occurs first in the content stream, before all the content you added via the `DirectContent`. Consequentially the image is (partially) covered by the rounded rectangle drawn thereafter.

Usually you can prevent this by only using either `Document` or `DirectContent` to draw in the same page area. In your case for example you should add the image to the `DirectContent`, too, not to the `Document`. For this replace

```
doc.Add(myImage);
```

by

```
pcb.AddImage(myImage);
```

As now all your drawings are done using the `DirectContent`, the image is drawn after the rounded rectangle and, therefore, is fully visible.

---

Two notes on your other code, though:

- You first define a path, then set the fill color and then fill the path:

  ```
  pcb.RoundRectangle(iXCoordinate + 5, iYCoordinate, 500, 100, 5);
  pcb.SetRGBColorFill(198, 226, 255);
  pcb.Fill();
  ```

  Strictly speaking this creates an invalid content stream as the PDF specification clearly requires that between a path definition and the matching path painting operation there may be nothing but a clipping path operator. Many PDF viewers will accept the invalid content stream, though.

  Thus, you should pull up the `pcb.SetRGBColorFill` before the `pcb.RoundRectangle`.
- If you want to stroke and fill the same path, you can define the path only once and call `pcb.FillStroke()` instead of defining it twice, once with a `Fill()` and once with a `Stroke()`.

Thus, a both simpler and more correct way to draw your form would be

```
pcb.SetRGBColorFill(198, 226, 255);
pcb.RoundRectangle(iXCoordinate + 5, iYCoordinate, 500, 100, 5);
pcb.FillStroke();
pcb.ResetRGBColorFill();
```